# How to know if script was run from django or from cli

Tags: python, django, command-line-interface

I have config.py that can be imported both from cli python script and from Django view.py

How to know in config.py - what process imported it?
May be there are some special vars in Django?

I tried

```
if sys.stdin.isatty():
    ***
```

but it seems not doing things I expected.

I cant use

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

because config.py is imported to the main file in cli.

In case of Cli I need parse command-line arguments with argparse.
In case of Django I need to import predefined django-config.py

Comment: What is the real underlying problem you are trying to solve? If you explain the original requirement rather than ask about how to get your perceived solution working, then maybe we can suggestion something better. Having a module reach back and try and parse command line arguments, bypassing whatever argument parsing and configuration system the program it is being used in is doing, doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if script ran from Django or command prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840736/how-to-detect-if-script-ran-from-django-or-command-prompt)

Answer (score 11):

I think the easiest approach would be to check `sys.argv`.

```
import sys

# sys.argv[0] Should output your script name in a command line environment
# It should output wsgi.py if you're using wsgi, etc.

if sys.argv[0] == 'manage.py':
   print('called with manage.py, I\'m on the command line!')

elif sys.argv[0] == 'mod_wsgi':
   print('called with with ]mod_wsgi, I\'m run by an HTTP server!')

# In the case where you have something other than Apache with mod_wsgi running your server
# you'll need to manually determine the contents of sys.argv[0]
# elif sys.argv[0] == '<your-servers-response-here>':
#   print('called by your HTTP server!')

else:
   print('called with %s, I don\'t know where that is!' % sys.argv[0])
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'run by Apache', but that specific test will not work for mod_wsgi, nor other WSGI servers that I know of.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton You're quite right. I copied that from another VirtualHost which was set up… creatively (translated: I didn't know what I was doing). `mod_wsgi` is in `sys.argv[0]` when using `Apache`.

Comment: My more robust test for whether running mod_wsgi under Apache is described in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/assorted-tips-and-tricks.html#determining-if-running-under-mod-wsgi

Comment: If you want to allow a little more of a fuzzy match, e.g. allowing python scripts to be run with `./manage.py` in the current working directory (instead of calling `python manage.py`), you can use `if 'manage.py' in sys.argv[0]`. A tiny fraction slower than a direct string comparison, but better UX.

Answer (score 0):

I would try piggy-backing off of the django settings:

```
try:
    from django.conf import settings
    x = settings.DATABASES['default']['name'] == 'the name of your default database'
    from_django = True
except ImportError, AttributeError, KeyError:
    from_django = False
```